Using Sixaxis in Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to use Sony Sixaxis controllers with Ubuntu 24.04, I tried the instructions in the below threads, but no success.  I had this running previously in 22.04 (as of July 2024)--don't know why it's a problem in 24.04.
How do I use a PlayStation 3 Sixaxis controller with Ubuntu to control games
My machine responds with the following when trying to add the repository:
ERROR: ppa 'falk-t-j/qtsixa' not found (use --login if private)

I next tried
How to connect Sixaxis on 15.10?
My machine cannot find sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools git
and responds with
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyqt4-dev-tools

When running these instructions,
How to connect Dualshock 3 controller (PS3 Sixaxis Gamepad) on Ubuntu 16.04?
it replies with
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python-dbus is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Unable to locate package pyqt4-dev-tools
E: Package 'python-dbus' has no installation candidate
